# Java ClassLoader dont load all classes in jar

Tags: java, reflection

I have 3 classes, say it's:

classA,classB,classC

And they packed into myClasses.jar

Next i load JAR to ClassLoader by code

```
Method method = URLClassLoader.class.getDeclaredMethod("addURL", new Class[]{URL.class});
method.setAccessible(true);
method.invoke(retClassLoader, new Object[]{jarFile.toURI().toURL()});
```

After that i open jar for list all classes and get them by code

```
try {
                ClassLoader classLoader = SMPBJars.loadExternalJar(jarFile);
                System.out.println("CL:"+Class.class.getClassLoader()+"|"+Platform.class.getClassLoader()+"|"+classLoader);

                JarInputStream jarFile;
                jarFile = new JarInputStream(new FileInputStream(selectedFile));
                JarEntry jarEntry;
                while (true) {
                    jarEntry = jarFile.getNextJarEntry();
                    if (jarEntry == null) {
                        break;
                    }
                    String foundName = jarEntry.getName().replaceAll("/", "\\.");
                    if (foundName.contains(".class")) {
                        String correctClassName = foundName.replaceAll(".class", "");
                        Class<?> getClass;
                        try {
                            getClass = Class.forName(correctClassName);
 System.out.println("LOAD CLASS:" + foundName);
                            }
                        } catch (ClassNotFoundException ex) {
                            System.out.println("CANT LOAD CLASS:" + foundName);
                        }
                    }
                }
                jarFile.close();
            } catch (Exception ex) {
                Logger.getLogger(SMPBSystemDirectoriesComponent.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
            }
```

I think what it's must work, but in log i got:

LOAD CLASS: classA

CANT LOAD CLASS: classB

CANT LOAD CLASS: classC

But, not every time!!!

If i re run project

i got loaded classB,classA not classC, another time classC loaded else not.

Why?

Is class loader need time to parse JAR? or smth?

Comment: Probably not your problem, but make sure you escape that '.' in the 'replaceAll' call because it's supposed to be a regex, which means it'll match 'Aclass.class' and change it to an empty string.

Comment: Thanks, promblem solved. Yes **mprivat** it's all by replaceAll :(

Comment: Correct part is: **String correctClassName = foundName.substring(0, foundName.length()-".class".length());**